# How to use wget to download a file which can be downloaded by firefox' default downloader?

Tags: wget

I try to use wget to download this but failed.

https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/raw-attachment/ticket/5069/rein_cmakelists2.patch

```
  sam@sam:/media/Data/code/ros/recognition/rein$ wget https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/raw-attachment/ticket/5069/rein_cmakelists2.patch
  --2012-10-04 16:29:30--  https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/raw-attachment/ticket/5069/rein_cmakelists2.patch
  Resolving code.ros.org (code.ros.org)... 157.22.19.21
  Connecting to code.ros.org (code.ros.org)|157.22.19.21|:443... connected.
  HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
  Retrying.

  --2012-10-04 16:29:32--  (try: 2)  https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/raw-attachment/ticket/5069/rein_cmakelists2.patch
  sam@sam:/media/Data/code/ros/recognition/rein$
```

But I can use firefox to download.

How to download this kind of file in wget?

Thank you~

Comment: Works here, at least in my case (Serbia)

Comment: Check this http://lwn.net/Articles/92727/ article. Turning off TCP window scaling might help you. `echo 0 >  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_window_scaling`

Comment: Permission denied when I run that command. What to do next? Thank you~

Comment: in fact i use axel instead, but also usually cannot download files that small (1.2kb).

Answer (score 4):

Some websites or servers block `wget` (and similar tools) in order to only allow downloads from a browser. You can trick the website into thinking that you are an actual browser. There are many examples available on google. Here is a particularly complete one taken from [askapache](http://www.askapache.com/linux/wget-header-trick.html). To find alternatives just google `wget pretend browser`.

```
wget 
  --referer="http://www.google.com" 
  --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6" 
  --header="Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5" 
  --header="Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5" 
  --header="Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate"
  --header="Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7" 
  --header="Keep-Alive: 300" 
  -dnv [THE URL; in your case: https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/raw-attachment]/ticket/5069/rein_cmakelists2.patch
```

This is one command, though I put it on several lines to increase readability. You can make it an alias to make it easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

This may due to the site use ticket along with cookies for downloading (some other methods too). So when using `wget` it's necessary to load cookies file as well as other option like user agent, etc.

For example:
`"wget" --trust-server-names -c -O jre-7u21-linux-x64.rpm --directory-prefix=/home/totti/Downloads --referer= http://java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp \?locale=en --load-cookies=/tmp/flashgot.7gavixy1.default/cookies --header=Cookie:s_vi=[CS]v1\|28BA8A90050109CA-6000011540153427[CE]\;\ --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0\ (X11\;\ Ubuntu\;\ Linux\ i686\;\ rv:16.0)\ Gecko/20100101\ Firefox/16.0 http://sdlc-esd.sun.com/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/7u21-b11/jre-7u21-linux-x64.rpm \?AuthParam=1366627766_80a413ae29c4b4d2e12ac7e334d61847\&GroupName=JSC\&FilePath=/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/7u21-b11/jre-7u21-linux-x64.rpm\&File=jre-7u21-linux-x64.rpm\&BHost=javadl.sun.com`

This can be easily done using the firefox extension `Flashgot`. (pls some one a add link to it)

Comment: 2018 calling: flashgot extension no longer maintained/compatible with Firefox